# Разные текстуры для разных камер

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру в юнити.  Возникла проблема: есть 2 камеры, которые одновременно отображают на экране объект, который обе камеры видят.

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы на первой камере объект рендерился с одним материалом, а с другой камеры был отрендерен другой материал.

Comment: Специалистов по шейдерам и пайплайну не так много, да и даже если умеешь, то с этим много возни. Проще двумя объектами на разных слоях и у камер разные настройки отрисовки слоев.